# If you rotate 1111 2 times (Right) is it still 1111?

Tags: assembly, rotation, bit

I know that when you rotate bits the ones that "fall off" are but back at the opposite end. My textbook gives me another answer without an explanation. I think it's either 1 I got the wrong number to begin with or I just don't understand rotation bits.
id appreciate it if you can answer my question.

Comment: Is this this some hypothetical 4-bit rotate instruction? If so, 1111 rotated _any number_ of times would still be 1111. Unless it's rotate-through-carry, in which case the answer is "It depends".

Comment: If your processor is 4 bits, then yes, it's still 1111.  If it's an 8 bit processor, then 00001111 rotated right twice would be 11000011.  Similarly for 16bit, 32bit, 64bit, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There's 2 ways of rotating (depending on what CPU you use), one "thru carry", and one that rotates only the operant (register/memory)

sample:
RLC (Z80)

```
         C          B7     B6    ...   B1      B0
       ____       ____    ____        ____    ____ 
      |    |     |    |  |    |      |    |  |    |   
  |---|    |<----|    |<-|    |<...<-|    |<-|    |<---
  |   |____|     |____|  |____|      |____|  |____|   |
  |                                                   |
  |___________________________________________________|
```

the content of topmost bit B7 will go to the Carry, B6 will go to B6 and so on, and the carry will be placed into B0
if you rotate 11111111 you will get 11111110 if the carry was clear, or 11111111 if the carry was set. In both cases, the carry after RLC will be set

RL does the same, but without the carry inbetween:

```
         B7     B6    ...   B1      B0
        ____    ____        ____    ____ 
       |    |  |    |      |    |  |    |   
  |----|    |<-|    |<...<-|    |<-|    |<---
  |    |____|  |____|      |____|  |____|   |
  |                                         |
  |_________________________________________|
```

if your register size is 4, and you rotate 1111 2 times, you will get 1111

if your register size is 8, and you rotate 1111 (which is actually 00001111), you will get 00111100

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: But my problem was that it was an 8bit pattern 0F I neglected the 0 and I thought it was just 1111. But it's 00001111 and when you rotate two times as my textbook asks you get 11000011. it was my fault for not clarifying the question.